# is a password necessary if mysql only allows connections from localhost

Tags: mysql, security, passwords, localhost, html

On a lot of public webpages, hosted by people at their own homes, they use their own desktops as webserver. Within this kind of setting usually I use a form of server sided language (like php) that connects to an MySQL server on the same machine. When installing this I always give an password to the “root” user and create a new user and password for the application (the php) script to use. Because both script and database are on the same “localhost” I always set the allowed connection to only allow connections from the local host and not from anywhere else. So both “root” and other “users” can only connect from when accessed from within the machine.

(the separate “root” and “user” accounts are made to give them separate privileges and an user can not drop scheme’s for example)

Today it struck me, **why am I setting passwords in MySQL?** Because if you want to connect to this database you already have to been logged in in the local machine. So, is setting passwords really necessary or just a redundant precaution?

And if it’s NOT an redundant precaution, why is it unsafe to not set a password.

(not that it is a big burden, but I have to remember all these passwords somehow, using encrypted systems this is not a real big problem, but if it could be avoided than……)

Comment: Either way, I don't see anything wrong with it. What you call a "redundant precaution" I call "layered security".

Comment: Nicely sad, but either way, is it necessary, can there be a way how this can go wrong or an reason why it is unwise to not set these passwords (ow, this really sounds strange to ask… and somewhat dumb)

Comment: In my experience, layering like this is a great protection against simple human error. What happens when this system gets moved in its entirety up to a shared hosting solution. Suddenly you're vulnerable to pivot attacks from anything else living on that box/in that network possibly. By doing the best security you can at each layer you protect yourself that little bit more from simple mistakes (as well as any potentially yet-to-be-considered attack vectors). I'll leave this here but I believe any further discussions would be out of place in the comments here and should go to chat.

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but from everything I've heard and read, you can't really keep good/dedicated hackers out. The best you can do is make it not worth their time.

Comment: Security and convenience are inversely proportional, and you can't have both. So your issue is not really about redundancy, it's about where you're comfortable drawing the line. If you have a corporate server with customer financial information, you put it way on the security side and deal with the inconvenience of 2FA and VPNs and spinning blade traps in the server room. If you're talking about a private home server that contains your taco recipes, it's not really a big deal to leave your MySQL passwordless.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Maybe until you realize that that server's on the same network as your home workstation which you do all of your personal finances on. Suddenly the value of security over convenience can really become apparent.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. I'm not suggesting that OP does not need a password, I'm suggesting that OP *might not* need a password. You can't say that it is always definitely a terrible thing to have a passwordless MySQL daemon. The point is that security issues never have definitive black and white answers, and certainly not ones that can be made based on hypotheticals.

Comment: Thanx Alex, I think CollinD and you gave good answers. Future changes could give need of the extra security layer. An other human developing or having his on share of the same devise could be a thread. And the trade off you propose makes it clear there will be no definitive answer on the Need of the password. So i realy only have a dull story on beer on the entire machine so no passwords needed for me.

Answer (score 0):

The comments on your post have mostly summed this up, but as far as I am aware, this is known as "Defense in depth" (See [1](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Defense_in_depth) and [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_%28computing%29)). Defense in depth is basically about avoiding having a single point of failure in your project - If your webserver is compromised, having a weak password means that you're just giving away your database for free. This would be equivalent to somebody breaking into your house to find you've placed your safe on the kitchen table and unlocked it.

If you're hosting an externally facing website that you hope to get a decent amount of traffic, making it as secure as possible is a good idea, unless you particularly like the idea of malicious users having direct access to your home network. That said, if you are expecting a decent amount of traffic I highly recommend hosting your website elsewhere - You may find that your home internet speeds suffer greatly as a result.